# How to stop for every 50 iterations in a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

Within a for loop I am doing a Mongo DB Query, the loop contains 1500 iterations.
So is there anyway that after 50 iterations, I want to give some time to the DB i.e. `Thread.currentThread().sleep(200);`

So please tell me how can I stop for a while after every 50:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    // ????
}
```

Comment: if (0 == i % 50) then sleep.  (i start from 1 is better)

Answer (score 11):

you use modulo for this

```
if( i % 50 == 0 ){
    Thread.sleep(200);
}
```

Comment: Beware this sleeps even if i == 0 :D

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to using modulo, which can use some cpu, is to use nested loops.

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j += m) {
    // before every m
    for(int i = j; i < j + m && i < n; i++) {
        // inner
    }
    // after every m
}
```

> this would be faster than %?

```
static int counter, counter2;

public static long testOneModLoop(int n, int m) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        counter++;
        if (i % m == m - 1)
            counter2++;
    }
    return System.nanoTime() - start;
}

public static long testTwoLoops(int n, int m) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j += m) {
        for (int i = j; i < j + m && i < n; i++) {
            counter++;
        }
        counter2++;
    }
    return System.nanoTime() - start;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int runs = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
        double time1 = (double) testOneModLoop(runs, 50) / runs;
        double time2 = (double) testTwoLoops(runs, 50) / runs;
        System.out.printf("Avg time for 1 loop: %.2f ns and 2 loops: %.2f ns%n",
                time1, time2);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Avg time for 1 loop: 6.09 ns and 2 loops: 0.78 ns
Avg time for 1 loop: 3.75 ns and 2 loops: 0.22 ns
Avg time for 1 loop: 3.67 ns and 2 loops: 0.19 ns
Avg time for 1 loop: 3.72 ns and 2 loops: 0.19 ns
Avg time for 1 loop: 3.67 ns and 2 loops: 0.19 ns
```

Comment: Just really curious, this would be faster than %? I would expect that computing the condition would take also some time ... really would love to know

Comment: For trivial inner loops it would make a big difference. For non-trivial loop, you might not see one.

Comment: @JanZyka I did a test and it's much faster for a trivial loop.

Comment: be careful: from what i could infer this microbenchmark looses a lot of time in `getstatic`/`putstatic` calls, up to the point where one version can be faster than another depending on whether the counters are static or local.

Comment: Results on my machine for local counters:

Comment: `Avg time for 1 loop: 0.02 ns; 2 loops: 0.49 ns; 1 loop, two counters : 0.33 ns; one bitwise and loop : 0.00 ns`. static ones `Avg time for 1 loop: 36.58 ns; 2 loops: 4.25 ns; 1 loop, two counters : 4.23 ns; one bitwise and loop : 5.81 ns`.

Comment: static fields are used to prevent code being optimised away. if you are getting average timings less than 0.2 ns it means you either have a 50 GHz cpu (1/0.02 ns) or your code is being optimised away as those fields are not needed.

Answer (score 3):

Use modulo like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      if( i%50 == 0){
         Thead.sleep(200);
      }
}
```

This will be true every time `i`  is a multiple of 50

Answer (score 3):

Building on Peter Lawrey's answer you can just put it all in one loop and avoid both modulo and sleeping in the first iteration:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; ++i, ++j) { //we increment both i and j
     if (j == 50) {                       // reset auxilliary counter and go to sleep
          j = 0;                       
          Thread.sleep(100);
     }
}
```

**edit**

By the way if you're worried about performance you can stop every 64 (or another power of two) iterations and use the fact that

```
n % k == n & (k - 1) when k is a power of two and n > 0
```

This way you can change the relatively expensive modulo operation to cheap bitwise `&`. Using power-of-two sizes in programming is generally a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is generally good idea, but when you asked:

```
if (i % 50 == 0 && i!=0) {
// Do something
}
```

Comment: Hehe, I love it too! That's the beauty of programming, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how to sleep every 'n' queries, I wonder if this is really what you want to be doing. Instead of (I suspect) getting a list of ids back and then querying the db for each document, can't you submit a more suitable query to the db and let it make use of its presumably optimised query API to find/return info.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{   
    // You code here...

    if(i%50==0)
       Thead.sleep(200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a simple condition inside for loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
 if(i % 100 == 0){// use 100 for 100 iterations and 50 for 50 iterations
   //your sleep code 
 }  
}
```